# how to convert RGB to YUV in interger and then restore

Tags: matlab, rgb, yuv

i want to convert a RGB picture to YUV,and the restore it .but when i calculate in MATLAB,i found The picture isn't quite true to the original. here is my  Operation in matlab !
here is my code:

```
%M file
clear all;  
clc;  
RGB = imread('11111.bmp');  
figure;imshow(RGB);

R = RGB(:,:,1);  
G = RGB(:,:,2);  
B = RGB(:,:,3);

Y0= 0.256788*R + 0.504129*G + 0.097906*B +  16;
U0=-0.148223*R - 0.290993*G + 0.439216*B + 128;
V0= 0.439216*R - 0.367788*G - 0.071427*B + 128;
Y= uint8(min(255,max(0,Y0)));% i want 8 bit YUV
U= uint8(min(255,max(0,U0)));
V= uint8(min(255,max(0,V0)));
RGB1R=Y+1.14 *V;
RGB1G=Y-0.39 *U-0.58*V;
RGB1B=Y+2.03*U;
RGB1=cat(3, RGB1R, RGB1G, RGB1B);
figure; imshow(RGB1);  
%M file
```

it should point out that the image is capsule endoscopy image.you could get it in wwww.gastrolab.net .i want the YUV is 8 bits interger,could anybody help me??

Comment: I assume you want to do that manually, not using MATLAB's built-in functions, right?

Comment: you mean i realize this method with a real CMOS optical sensors ???

Comment: No, the question is: can the solution contain MATLAB-commands like `rgb2ycbcr()` or do you want to do it using formulas like `Y0= 0.256788*R + 0.504129*G + 0.097906*B +  16;`?

Comment: that is ok ,thank you very much. i use the built in function rgb2ycbcr() and ycbcr2rgb() in matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert between RGB and YCbCr, MATLAB offers the functions [`rgb2ycbcr`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2ycbcr.html) and [`ycbcr2rgb`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ycbcr2rgb.html). YCbCr and YUV are then related by

```
Y = Y
U = 0.872021 Cb
V = 1.229951 Cr
```

To convert an RGB image to YUV, you can thus use

```
RGB = imread('11111.bmp');  
YCBCR = rgb2ycbcr(RGB);
YUV(:,:,1) = YCBCR(:,:,1);               % Y  -> Y
YUV(:,:,2) = 0.872021 * YCBCR(:,:,2);    % Cb -> U
YUV(:,:,3) = 1.229951 * YCBCR(:,:,3);    % Cr -> V
```

and to convert it back, use

```
YCBCR1(:,:,1) = YUV(:,:,1);               % Y -> Y
YCBCR1(:,:,2) = YUV(:,:,2) / 0.872021;    % U -> Cb
YCBCR1(:,:,3) = YUV(:,:,3) / 1.229951;    % V -> Cr
RGB1 = ycbcr2rgb(YCBCR1);
```

Note that if you are using `uint8` as type for `RGB`, then `YCBCR` and `YUV` will be `uint8` too and the conversion will be lossy. For a testimage of mine, the maximum difference between `RGB` and `RGB1` was

```
max(abs(RGB(:)-RGB1(:)))
ans = 
     4
```

To have a lossless conversion, you should use the `double` datatype. Note that MATLAB assumes that for `uint8` images the values are between 0 and 255, while for `double` images, the values are between 0 and 1, so they would need to be scaled.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is what i want ,thank you again

Comment: that is it,i run it in matlab , now is ok.

Comment: Ok, perfect. If this (or any) answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Though of course there is no obligation to do this.